# @import "breakpoint"; throws not found error

Tags: sass, breakpoints, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

I was working on this project yesterday using Sass and Breakpoint and everything was fine. This morning however when I went to compile using sass --watch .. I am getting this error:

> error ../sass/screen.scss (Line 6: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
>   Load path: /Users/MOD3/Sites/GABE/stylesheets/stylesheets)

I am not sure why it is not finding breakpoint anymore but I am sure it is installed. I read something about it needing to be an absolute path, but where do I get that path from? Any idea how to fix this? It was working yesterday...

Answer (score 2):

Breakpoint currently does not work with vanilla Sass as it requires a small bit of Ruby that is not available until Sass 3.3. My intuition is that you probably ran `sass --compass --watch` to allow Breakpoint to run through Compass. If not, I would highly encourage you to compile through Compass or Breakpoint will not work as expected.

UPDATE:

Issue was solved by running `compass watch` from same folder as `config.rb`.

Comment: If I compile through compass I keep getting this message You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory. no matter where I am in the project directory :S

Comment: Ok I compiled with compass now, but it is still giving the same error about breakpoint

Comment: You're probably missing `require 'breakpoint'` in your config.rb (assuming you're using the gem version rather than a local file)

Comment: I do have 
require "breakpoint" in my config.rb file, as well as @import "breakpoint"; in the sass file. No idea why it is not finding breakpoint anymore. I reinstalled and still a problem...

Comment: Let us please continue debugging this in the Breakpoint issue queue:
https://github.com/Team-Sass/breakpoint/issues/52

Comment: @SayraLopez, please accept the answer by clicking the "√" icon next to it.